# How can I see the log of Spark job server task?

Tags: apache-spark

I deployed spark job server according https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver. Then I created a job server project, and uploaded to the hob server. While I run the project, how can I see the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible to see the logs while running a project. I browsed through the source code and couldn't find any references to a feature like this, and it's clearly not a feature of the ui. It seems like your only option would be to view the logs after running a job, which are stored by default in `/var/log/job-server`, which you probably already know.

Comment: Yes, I already know. And it just keeps track of the history of job server, it is not the log for the details of the job. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Now I use a alternative way to see the log for the particular job, to check whether my code have bug. I'm using spark-submit, I test the code on the spark server first, before I upload the jar to job server.

Comment: Yeah sorry I couldn't help more, hopefully this will be implemented in the future!